# Converting/adding support for multiple instances of a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've forked the filamentgroup daterangepicker* which seems to be no longer maintained, in order to include some posted fixes and address the issue of it only supporting a single datarangepicker on a page.

I've read the how to docs on setting up a jquery plugin and for setting up a jquery widget. But the issue with widget is that if you pass multiple elements to the widget it will create a separate widget for each element. One feature of the daterange picker is to pass 2 input fields to supply as the start and end of a single daterange. So the multiple elements treated separately is not useful in this case.

So is there other best practices beside using $.widget to convert an existing plugin to allow having mutiple uses of it on a page.

I'm guessing that the vars defined in the plugin closure just need to be not there unless they are static values used for all instances, the instance specific vars would need to be associated with the selector passed in via a data attribute or an id that the plugin keeps an indexed array of? Am I on the right track? missing something else beside just the vars defined?

Any pointers or examples for how to add support for multiple instances of a jquery plugin are appreciated.

*the origin code is from - http://filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker_v2/

on git - https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-UI-Date-Range-Picker/blob/master/js/daterangepicker.jQuery.js

Comment: Is that first link a git repo? Just clicking it I get a Forbidden error.

Comment: sorry @Jared I corrected the link, seems it was a redirected url

Comment: I still have the same problem. Are you required to be logged in to get to that link?

Comment: I changed the link again. The new link is the example page; in the example's green headerbar is the link that has the details

Answer (score 0):

One aspect of best practice would be to invoke the plugin on empty containers (divs/spans) and to generate the two date fields on initialisation.

That way, you could create as many datespan widgets as you need with a single statement and with minimum effort in preparing the HTML.

[This tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) provides arguably the best plugin pattern available. It's an awkward cuss right up to the moment you realise it's super-cool.